# Attempting to develop an Android app with PhoneGap and Meteor - need assistance

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

Looking for some help building an Android app using PhoneGap with Meteor.

I've seen answers here on how one can essentially build a "thin-client" PhoneGap app that points to a meteor server and renders it and that essentially works for me.

However, I'd like to do this a little more client-side ("thick-client") and therefore would like to bring the Meteor client side code (js,css) into PhoneGap and have that code call the Meteor server remotely.  I've seen some approaches to hack in a hardcoded URL in places but they aren't working for me (app.html comes up blank in the emulator - I don't think any/all of the referenced js files are loading properly).

I've also attempted to change my meteor client code to use Meteor.connect, but I don't know how to authenticate the user with the remote server.  I'm using the accounts- packages and it always authenticates with my local machine server.

So my questions:

(A) Has anyone pulled something like this off? (esp. for Android using a Windows dev machine)

(B) If this is possible, what files need to be pulled from the meteor bundle into the phonegap folders and where exactly do they go?  What other tweaks are necessary?

(C) If using Meteor.connect is the way to go (for remote data), how does one tell the auth packages to talk to the remote server?

Thanks mucho..

Answer (score 0):

It would require some manual editing but it should be possible:

1. Make sure that all your images/resources are referenced such that they can be available locally (/ use relative paths)
2. In your project directory use `meteor bundle` to create a tarball of your project http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorbundle
3. Extract your tarball and use the `index.html` file in your PhoneGap or Cordova project www folder, perhaps after a network check or something as the meteor project
4. Copy the stuff in the static (which come from the `public` directory of your meteor project such as images) to your www too
5. Publish your bundle onto a server
6. Edit your `index.html` file so that the referenced javascript loads from your server instead

That should get all the stuff to run locally on the phone but only fetch the collections, subscriptions, meteor calls & stuff via websocket/long polling from your server